# Unable to run automated tests against DirectX applications after installing platform update kb2670838

Tags: session, directx, sessionid, windows-update

I work on automated tests for DirectX based applications that run on various automated servers.  The servers are setup to run as a service, which means when the tests execute they are executed under session 0.

However, the tests started failing after installing the windows platform update kb2670838.  When initializing the application, a DXGI_ERROR_NOT_CURRENTLY_AVAILABLE error occurs after a call to CreateSwapChain.

I have found that some API calls do not work under session 0.  (See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404562(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

But last week this worked.  I posted this in various Microsoft forums, but it seems no one else is having this problem.  So my question is has anyone else experienced this?  And how did you work around it?

Comment: I would interpret "no one else is having this problem" as "no one else ever tried to do this".

Comment: So no one else: 1) Develops a DirectX application.  2) Writes functional tests that launch the UI. 3) Executes the tests in an environment that runs as a service (e.g. bamboo or jenkins)?  I suppose that's possible, but I am holding out hope this scenario isn't that uncommon.

Comment: Frankly, I find your claim this (using DirectX in Session 0) used to work far more amazing than the fact no-one else has reported in with the same experience. Did your servers perhaps use the Software Rasterizer in the past?